Unable to start spring microservice using docker compose
Creating spring boot micro-service with config server.
There are 3 services currently:

config server
post service
user service

Issue is config server is able to start properly but the post and user service can't.
The following is docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.12-management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    healthcheck:
      test: rabbitmq-diagnostics check_port_connectivity
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 5s
    networks:
      - app-network

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: blog
      POSTGRES_USER: postgresuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512m
    volumes:
      - ~/volume/userservice-postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      - app-network

  configserver:
    image: example/configserver
    container_name: configserver
    ports:
      - "8071:8071"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 700m
    depends_on:
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl --fail --silent http://localhost:8071/actuator/health/readiness | grep UP || exit 1"
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 20s
    networks:
      - app-network

  userservice:
    image: example/userservice
    container_name: userservice
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: userservice
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5431/userservice
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgresuser
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
      CONFIG_SERVER: http://configserver:8071
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: prod
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 700m
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_healthy
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy
      postgres:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - app-network

  postservice:
    image: example/postservice
    container_name: postservice
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: postservice
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5431/postservice
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgresuser
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
      CONFIG_SERVER: http://configserver:8071
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: prod
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 700m
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_healthy
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy
      postgres:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

This is the stacktrace:
serservice       | 
userservice       | 2024-08-05T07:32:22.288Z  INFO 1 --- [userservice] [  restartedMain] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8071/
userservice       | 2024-08-05T07:32:22.289Z  INFO 1 --- [userservice] [  restartedMain] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Exception on Url - http://localhost:8071/:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8071/userservice/default": Connection refused. Will be trying the next url if available
userservice       | 2024-08-05T07:32:22.290Z  INFO 1 --- [userservice] [  restartedMain] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8071/
userservice       | 2024-08-05T07:32:22.290Z  INFO 1 --- [userservice] [  restartedMain] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Exception on Url - http://localhost:8071/:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8071/userservice/prod": Connection refused. Will be trying the next url if available
userservice       | 2024-08-05T07:32:22.393Z ERROR 1 --- [userservice] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
userservice       | 
userservice       | org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientFailFastException: Could not locate PropertySource and the resource is not optional, failing
userservice       |     at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.doLoad(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:210) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
userservice       |     at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientRetryBootstrapper.lambda$initialize$1(ConfigClientRetryBootstrapper.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
userservice       |     at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.load(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:95) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
userservice       |     at 

application.yml looks like this:
spring:
  application:
    name: userservice
  config:
    import: "configserver:${CONFIG_SERVER:http://localhost:8071/}"




looks like your services need to execute a command: to initialize the application to start; or build the project using a Dockerfile which runs a CMD or EntryPoint to start the app / service.

@TheoNeUpKID these commands are already exists in docker images.

I see. Then I would recommend starting each service, and remove the depends_on prop in the docker-compose file. One or more of service STATES are unhealthy or an exception is occurring when starting. You can also just make it as depends_on without the condition prop to see what may be happening

What does it fail with?

@M.Deinum updated pls see.

@TheoNeUpKID userservice and postservice is not starting.

@TheoNeUpKID its already there, If i execute microservices wihout docker compose file it is executing perfectly fine.

the service  request  cloud config center with "http://localhost:8071"??, but you define them in  different container, please define the url as container name in your application.yaml

@Peng yes I also defined this. Pls see the update

try use import: "configserver:${CONFIG_SERVER:  http:// configserver:8071/}"  insteand of current config, at least ,we 'd better ensure that  config center in docker is accessible

I doubt that your config server is deployed at localhost from the POV of docker. localhost is within your Docker container. Instead you should use the service name.

@Peng If I do that then I wouldn't be able to run it locally without involving docker compose..

so  just  try for test , if that run normally, the issue obviously is  that  the env CONFIG_SERVER in docker compose had not inject into spring


Unable to start spring microservice using docker compose


Issue is config server is able to start properly but the post and user
service can't.

I assume you have the issue is because of the misconfiguration of the URL for the Config Server in your Docker Compose file.
Please, be sure that your Config Server URL in the environment variables of your userservice and your postservice points to the configserver service.
userservice:
  userservice:
   ...
    environment:
   ...
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/userservice  
      CONFIG_SERVER: http://configserver:8071 

postservice:
  postservice:
   ...
    environment:
   ...
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: 
jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postservice  
      CONFIG_SERVER: http://configserver:8071 

Furthemore, pay attention to the next points, please.

Check that your database URL uses the correct port - 5432, which is the default port of PostgreSQL within Docker network.

Be sure that the health check and start periods of all of your services have sufficient time to start.

Check that all services in Docker are correctly attached to the app-network and can communicate with each other.


P.s.
Check configserver logs to understand if it starts correctly and that configurations works as expected.

this too not working

@Cody could you give me some more details what is not working? share some logs with me
